# If a misdemeanor crime happens on a plane, where is the jurisdiction?

Tags: united-states, air-travel

If a misdemeanor crime happens during a plane flight, where is the jurisdiction?

For example, suppose a plane is flying from New York to California and while the plane is flying over Idaho, one passenger steals money out of another's purse (petty theft). The victim later discovers the theft and wants to make a complaint against the thief. What is the proper jurisdiction for the complaint?